# How to do letter spacing every two letters with CSS only?

Tags: html, css

Here is my html code:

```
<span class="number">0102030405</span>
```

I want to obtain this:

**01 02 03 04 05**

Here what I have tried:

```
.number {
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    text-weight: bold;
}
```

but the spacing is applied between each number. How can I apply the spacing every two numbers ?

***Note:***
 I'm looking for a **CSS only solution**.

Comment: Why can't you separate them in the markup and then use `word-spacing`?

Comment: There isn't an `nth-letter` option, like there is for nth-child. apparently there's talk of implementing it, but it's not in css yet.

Comment: In these days it isn't possible using CSS only (without JS), but once in the future... http://blogs.adobe.com/webplatform/2012/03/22/adobe-webkit-hackathon-summary/

Comment: @Kyle Shevlin because he is looking for a generic solution, and also probably doesn't want to prevent copy/paste

Answer (score 18, accepted):

For a CSS only solution, without an `nth-letter` selector you're going to be dealing with workarounds. There is no `nth-letter` currently (although [CSSWG is discussing it](https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/3208)) as you'll no doubt know, so here's a possible workaround albeit an ugly one.

If you're happy to tweak for each instance of `.number` then you could use the following approach based on splitting the pairs of numbers using columns. Works pretty well for the given example:

```
.number {
    width: 8em;
    display: block;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    columns: 5;
    column-gap: 0.2em;
}
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/WgRs6/

The `width`, `columns` and `column-gap` values will need to be tweaked depending on the numbers in the markup as well as the chosen font size. You'd also need to tweak them to change the space between the columns. Unfortunately, this would certainly break if there are numbers with different amount of digits (e.g. 1, 200, 3, 9000, 42, 100000). You asked for splitting between two numbers so hopefully that shouldn't be an issue for you.

Ideally you'd be able to use [lettering.js](http://letteringjs.com/), or any JavaScript which would split your letters into distinct `span` elements that you could then combine with `.number span:nth-child(2n)` to add your desired spacing. See: http://jsfiddle.net/SSq7M/

Comment: Great answer it works like a charm :) Last point, I want to underline the numbers but the line is cutted too. Do you know how to underline the gaps also ?

Comment: Add `border-bottom` to the `.number` class. It will span the width of the block.

Comment: Any solution that touches the input is problematic since it breaks the basic copy/paste functionality. Too bad there is still no view only solution for this (and also for thousands sperator). But nice workaround though. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether you can do it using css.Anyway you can do this using javascript. The code will be as follows :

```
 String.prototype.chunk = function(n) {
   var space = [];
   for(var i=0, len=this.length; i < len; i += n) {
     space.push(this.substr(i, n))
   }
   return space
 };

"0102030405".chunk(2).join('  ');
```

Check [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mijoemathew/Fysr4/)

Comment: A possible workaround but OP is looking for a css-only approach

Comment: This adds spaces and has nothing to do with the question.

Answer (score 0):

It cannot be done in CSS, because there is no selector that would refer to, say, the 3rd character in the content of an element or the the first two characters. CSS operates on elements and pseudo-elements, and no currently defined pseudo-element is suitable for this.

If possible, the content should be modified server-side or, if that’s not possible, with client-side JavaScript so that either the character pairs appear as elements or there are space characters between them, e.g. `<span class="number">01 02 03 04 05</span>`. In the latter case, you can use `word-spacing` (probably with a negative value) to tune the amount of spacing.